# Python Class returning an empty dictionary

Tags: python, oop

Newbie needing some help making code object-oriented.

I am trying to write a class with different methods for processing XML files. One of these methods has a goal of returning a dictionary with the embedded attachment's filename and the encoded datastring as key and value respectively.

I have managed to get this to work outside of the class:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('invoice.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

namespace = {
    'cac': 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2',
    'cbc': 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2',
    'ext': 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2',
    'ccts': 'urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2',
    'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
}

attachments = {}

for document in root.findall('cac:AdditionalDocumentReference', namespace):
    filename = document.find('cbc:ID', namespace).text
    print(filename)

    # Find the embedded file
    for child in document.findall('cac:Attachment', namespace):
        attachment = child.find('cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject', namespace).text
        attachments[filename] = attachment
```

But I have been unable to translate this into a class method, as the class method returns an empty dictionary. The code I am working on:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Invoice:
    """
    Common tasks in relation to EHF invoices.
    """

    namespace = {
            'cac': 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2',
            'cbc': 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2',
            'ext': 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2',
            'ccts': 'urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2',
            'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        }

    attachments = {}

    def __init__(self, invoice):
        """Initialize invoice attributes."""
        self.invoice = invoice

        # Dictionary for namespace used in EHF invoices
        self.namespace = self.namespace

    def encoded_attachments(self):
        """
        Return the embedded attachments from the EHF invoice in encoded form
        as a dictionary.

        Keys = filenames
        Value = base64 encoded files
        """
        
        for document in self.invoice.findall('cac:AdditonalDocumentReference', self.namespace):
            # Find filename
            filename = document.find('cbc:ID', self.namespace).text
        
            # Find the embedded file
            for child in document.findall('cac:Attachment', namespace):
                attachment = child.find('cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject', self.namespace).text

                # Add filename and attachment to dictionary
                self.attachments[filename] = attachment
        
        return(self.attachments)

tree = ET.parse('invoice.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

ehf = Invoice(root)

attach_dict = ehf.encoded_attachments()
print(attach_dict)
```

I think there is something important I am missing about classes. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

Part of the xml file. Encoded data replaced with a dummy text string.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
    xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017#compliant#urn:fdc:peppol.eu:2017:poacc:billing:3.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
    <cbc:ProfileID>urn:fdc:peppol.eu:2017:poacc:billing:01:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID>1060649</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2020-01-23</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:DueDate>2020-02-07</cbc:DueDate>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:TaxPointDate>2020-01-23</cbc:TaxPointDate>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>NOK</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cbc:BuyerReference>N/A</cbc:BuyerReference>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>invoice_attachment_filename.pdf</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:DocumentTypeCode>130</cbc:DocumentTypeCode>
        <cbc:DocumentDescription>CommercialInvoice</cbc:DocumentDescription>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="application/pdf" filename="1060649.pdf">BASE64ENCODEDTEXT</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
</Invoice>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's clear what you want to achieve, but can you also post a (part) of the xml file you are trying to parse so people can run and debug the code as you do?

Comment: @Ronald Added portion of the XML relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is (drum roll...) Everything is correct, but compare old and new code here:

```
old: for document in root.findall('cac:AdditionalDocumentReference', namespace)
new: for document in self.invoice.findall('cac:AdditonalDocumentReference', self.namespace)
                                                    ^
```

By the way, you can leave out the line `self.namespace = self.namespace`.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I missed that. Spend an embarrasing amount of time wracking my head because of that typo.

Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, sometimes... but thanks to the example file I was able to actually run your code and quickly pinpointed that `self.invoice.findall(...)` returned an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of `self` is not consistent

```
for child in document.findall('cac:Attachment', **namespace**):
    attachment = child.find('cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject', **self.namespace**).text
```

Comment: Thank you. Edited the code, though it didn't solve the issue I'm having.

Answer (score -1):

You are making two mistakes here.
One is that you are using class variables (read up here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)
The second one is what gokaai said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63034395/3683639).

This should work:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


class Invoice:
    """
    Common tasks in relation to EHF invoices.
    """

    def __init__(self, invoice):
        """Initialize invoice attributes."""
        self.invoice = invoice
        self.namespace = {
            'cac': 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-3',
            'cbc': 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-3',
            'ext': 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-3',
            'ccts': 'urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:1',
            'xsi': 'http://www.w2.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        }
        self.attachments = {}

    def encoded_attachments(self):
        """
        Return the embedded attachments from the EHF invoice in encoded form
        as a dictionary.

        Keys = filenames
        Value = base64 encoded files
        """

        for document in self.invoice.findall('cac:AdditonalDocumentReference', self.namespace):
            # Find filename
            filename = document.find('cbc:ID', self.namespace).text

            # Find the embedded file
            for child in document.findall('cac:Attachment', self.namespace):
                # Add filename and attachment to dictionary
                self.attachments[filename] = child.find('cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject', self.namespace).text

        return self.attachments
```

Comment: *Should* work or *will* work? I don't see why using class variables is a mistake?

Comment: I could not test it, as I don't have the input XML. If you use class variables here and use multiple different objects of this class they will overwrite each others variables. That is why it is wrong to use class variables in this case. If you want to use them, you need to make sure you only have one object of that class at any point in time, making the class itself obsolete.

Comment: That is why I asked for a sample XML file in my first comment. A class variable is available for all of its members. The namespace variable seems typically suitable to use as a class variable because it is not changed nor member specific.

Comment: Ok, you could make `namespace` a class variable, but then the `self.namespace` he is using everywhere is wrong. I don't know if each of his instances should have the same namespace. But yes, you are right, `namespace` can probably be a class variable.

Comment: On the contrary, `self` is a reference to the class which is passed to the function. So the `self.` notation is required to access the variable. Alternatively you could use the class name itself (instead of `self`) depending on you intents.

Comment: Nope, look at his constructor: He has `self.namespace = self.namespace` which will create a instance variable from the class variable. Every time he uses `self.namespace` he is actually using the instance variable, not the class variable. So the only way to get to the class variable is using the class name, as you said. The whole mixing of class and instance variables in the example is just messy.

Comment: It *does* create a new instance variable indeed. In this code it is an unnecessary copy  and therefore (as I stated in my answer) that line can be left out. It doesn't do any real harm to the code though.